# How to dynamically generate numbers in play template?

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to generate numbers 1-100 in my numbers.scala.html file

```
<select class="form-control" value="@form("number")">
    @for(var a <- 1 to 10){
        <option>@a</option>
    }
</select>
```

But it creates error. Supposedly play templates do not support creating variables. Can I do that this way or do I have to write javascript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the `var` - it's implied in Scala templates:

```
@for(a <- 1 to 10) {
    <option>@a</option>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the var declaration I tested this and it works fine

```
@for(a <- 1 to 10){
    @a
}
```